# two real closed fields- algebraic elements

Tags: real-algebra

If R_1\subset R_2 are two real closed fields (R_2 is an extension of R_1), then is it always the case that R_1 contains {R_2}_alg; By the latter I mean algebraic elements of R_2.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "algebraic elements of $R_2$"? Do you mean those elements that are algebraic over $R_1$? Then the answer is yes. There is a straightforward proof: the only algebraic extension of $R_1$ is $R_1[i]$, and $i \notin R_2$. (where $i^2 = -1$)

Comment: As far as I know, "algebraic" without an "over $k$" clause, always means algebraic over the prime field, in this case $\mathbb Q$. 

Comment: That was my first thought too, but that makes the question nearly trivial.

Answer (score -1):

I think I've found it out. If R_1\subset R_2 are two real closed fields, then (R_1)_alg should be the same as (R_2)_alg, since otherwise (R_2)_alg would be a proper real extension of (R_1)_alg contradicting real-closedness of (R_1)_alg.

Comment: And are both of these identified with the algebraic reals?

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: Yes, the algebraic elements of any real-closed field are (under the obvious identification) the algebraic reals.